# jede, jeder, jedes: Adjektiv?

Tags: adjective, indefinite-pronoun

Mir ist nicht klar, weshalb in folgenden Sätzen "jede, jeder, jedes" ein Adjektiv sein soll?

> Ich habe **jedes** Wort gehört, das du gesagt hast. 
>  Er widmet
>   **jeden** freien Moment seinem Hobby. 
>   **Jeder** seiner Schritte wurde sorgfältig beobachtet. 
>  Sie ist in **jeder** Hinsicht schön. 
>  Er betrachtete **jeden** einzelnen von ihnen genau. 
>  Sie hinterfragten **jede** Kleinigkeit, die sie
>   sagte.

Wie komme ich darauf, dass das ein Adjetiv ist?

Wenn ich im Langenscheidt Wörterbuch englisch-deutsch das englische Wort "every" nachschaue, dann gibt es eine deutsche Uebersetzung dazu und daneben steht, dass es sich um ein Adjektiv handeln soll.

[image]

Ebenso im "Merriam-Webster’s Advanced Learner’s English Dictionary": -> adj.
[image]

Mir ist nicht klar, weshalb das nicht ein Indefinitpronomen ist und weshalb es im Wörterbuch nicht eine Sektion "Indefinitpronomen" gibt.

Comment: *Jeder/jede/jedes* ist ein Pronomen, kein Adjektiv. Das englische *every* ist ein sogenannter *determiner*, eine Wortart, die es im Deutschen nicht gibt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wenn es sich um ein gedrucktes Wörterbuch handeln sollte, müßten irgendwo Erklärungen untergebracht sein, welche Wortarten angesetzt werden. Ich vermute, daß die Wortart *Artikel*, wenn sie überhaupt aufgeführt wird, nur für den bestimmten und unbestimmten Artikel verwendet wird.

Wörter wie *every, my* werden dann als Adjektive gewertet, weil sie attributiv sind, also mit einem Nomen stehen, während Pronomen selbständig sind. Wörter wie *this, which* werden doppelt aufgeführt: Als Pronomen, wenn sie selbständig sind, als Adjektive, wenn sie attributiv sind.

> *Pronomen (stellvertretend, substantivisch)*:
> If I should die, think only **this** of me.
> **Which** of you is without sin?
>
> *Adjektive (begleitend, attributiv)*:
> **This book** fills a much-needed gap.
> **Which song** do you like the most?
> **Every sperm** is sacred.
> **My home** is **my castle**.

Der Duden folgt einer anderen Tradition, in der alle diese Wörter den Pronomen zugeschlagen werden, und darauf hingewiesen wird, daß sie begleitend-attributiv oder stellvertretend-substantivisch verwendet werden können.

Neuere Einteilungen der Wortarten, bei denen diese Wörter stattdessen als *Artikelwörter* oder *Determinantien* zusammengefaßt werden, sind wohl noch nicht bis in die Wörterbücher vorgedrungen.

Answer (score 2):

Das Wort *»jedes«* ist kein Adjektiv. Es ist ein Indefinitpronomen, und somit ein Determinativ.

> Ich habe *xxx* Wort gehört.

Das, was an die Stelle der drei *x* hingehört, ist ein [Determinativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinativ_(Wortart)). Das ist ein Überbegriff für eine Gruppe mehrerer verschiedener Wortarten, die alle gemeinsam haben, dass sie innerhalb einer Nominalgruppe das Nomen näher bestimmen. Dazu gehören:

- **Artikel**

  > Ich habe **das** Wort gehört.
  >   Ich habe **ein** Wort gehört.
- **Demonstrativpronomen**

  > Ich habe **dieses** Wort gehört.
- **Interrogativpronomen**

  > **Welches** Wort habe ich gehört?
- **Possessivpronomen**

  > Ich habe **dein** Wort gehört.
- **Indefinitpronomen**

  > Ich habe **kein** Wort gehört.
  >   Ich habe **jedes** Wort gehört.

Adjektive können in Sätzen wie den obigen nicht alleine vor einem Nomen stehen:

> Falsch: *Ich habe **lautes** Wort gehört.*

Aber man kann Determinative mit Adjektiven kombinieren:

> Ich habe **das laute** Wort gehört.
>   Ich habe **ein lautes** Wort gehört.
>   Ich habe **dieses laute** Wort gehört.
>   **Welches laute** Wort habe ich gehört?
>   Ich habe **dein lautes** Wort gehört.
>   Ich habe **kein lautes** Wort gehört.
>   Ich habe **jedes laute** Wort gehört.

Comment: Sollte es nicht ich habe jedes laute Wort heißen?